# Valgrind error conditional jump

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm writing a program that loads input until a specific word is typed in,in this case its word "konec".Although my program seems to work just about ok,I can't solve this Valgrind error

```
==16573== Memcheck, a memory error detector   
==16573== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.  
==16573== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info  
==16573== Command: ./s_main_o  
==16573==   
==16573== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==16573==    at 0x4C2A020: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:711)  
==16573==    by 0x4008D7: main (main.c:41)  
==16573==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  
==16573==    at 0x4C28CCE: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)  
==16573==    by 0x40089C: main (main.c:38)  
==16573==   
==16573== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==16573==    at 0x4C2A024: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:711)  
==16573==    by 0x4008D7: main (main.c:41)  
==16573==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation  
==16573==    at 0x4C28CCE: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)  
==16573==    by 0x40089C: main (main.c:38)  
==16573==   
==16573==   
==16573== HEAP SUMMARY:  
==16573==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==16573==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,125 bytes allocated  
==16573==   
==16573== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible  
==16573==   
==16573== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v  
==16573== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

And here part of the used code

```
int main() {

    int numberOfWords, i;
    char** words;
    char* word;
    int* rarity;
    char* konec = "konec";
    int amount = 0;
    double percentage;
    words = malloc(10 * sizeof (char*));
    rarity = calloc(256, sizeof (int));
    numberOfWords = 0;
    words[0] = 0;
    int working = 1;

    while (working == 1) {
        int length = 0;
        word = calloc((length + 1),sizeof (char));
        char c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            length++;
            word = realloc(word, length + 1);
            word[length - 1] = c;
        }
        if (strcmp(word, konec) == 0) {
            working = 0;
            free(word);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have found lots of topics discussing the same problem,but I wasn't able to find solution anyway.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Don't use `realloc()` like that, use a temporary pointer, and always check that any *`alloc` function did not return `NULL` before dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: You need to add a nul terminator to `word`.  At present, `strcmp` reads beyond the end of the memory you allocate looking for the first zero byte.

Comment: `char c;` you should make that an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not add a null terminator on reallocation:

```
word = realloc(word, length + 1);
word[length - 1] = c;
```

At this point, `word` string is not terminated, so `strcmp` may go off its end in search of null terminator. For example, when you type `"ko"`, `strcmp` will determine that characters 0 and 1 are the same, and try checking `word[2]` - a location that your program did not set.

Add this line to fix the problem:

```
word[length] = '\0';
```

You should also add code to `free` `word` when comparison to `konec` is unsuccessful.

**Note:** You are not using `realloc` correctly: instead of assigning it back to `word`, you should assign it to `temp`, and check it for `NULL`. Otherwise, you would have no way of freeing previously allocated word when `realloc` fails.